# Floor insulation benefits?

Tags: insulation, floor

I am experimenting with a floor design which would be heavy stone slab on a blocking lattice (no floorboards) or maybe on steel joists. Either way, such a design will allow a pretty rapid heat transfer through the floor.

Although the basement will be heated, would it still be desirable to insulate the floor by placing insulation under it? That would create two different zones.

Comment: Only if you want two different zones. Do you?

Comment: @isherwood I don't know the advantages and disadvantages, thats why i am asking.

Comment: It would make sense if you plan to have significantly different temperatures on opposite sides of the floor.

Comment: You're most of the way to building a **hypocaust**, the traditional Roman radiant heated floor...